# Регулярное выражение для подстроки, которой не должен предшествовать символ

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++

Вроде как нетипичная задача. Выполняю последовательно поиск подстрок в строке и их замену на идентификаторы вида `<i#>`. Проблема в том, что после одной проверки мне нужно прогнать изменённую строку через выражение `"[a-z][a-z0-9]*"` (слово из букв и цифр, начинающееся с буквы). Получается, что идентификатор будет повторно распознан и на выходе я получу что-то в духе `<<i15>>`, что является ошибкой.

Каким образом следует модифицировать выражение `"[a-z][a-z0-9]*"`, чтобы оно не принимало подстроки, перед которыми стоит `<`. Например:

```
"as4s" - найдено as4s
"s sd4" - найдено s, sd4
"<asd sad" - найдено sad
"<asd" - ничего не найдено
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, кажется, вы оставляли другой ответ, который выглядел более убедительно. Не успел проверить, так как был занят другим всё это время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни один из [диалектов языка регулярных выражений, реализованных в c++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type), не поддерживает [негативный просмотр назад (с отрицанием) (negative lookbehind)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4): `(?<!regex)`.

Чтобы симулировать `(?<!<)` можно использовать: `(?:^|[^<])\b`, что распознаёт либо начало строки либо любой символ отличный от `<`. При этом `\b` используется, чтобы не съесть начало идентификатора.

Полный пример:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  regex re("(?:^|[^<])\\b([a-z][a-z0-9]*)");
  for (const string& s : { "as4s", "s sd4", "<asd",  "<asd sad", } )
    copy(sregex_token_iterator(begin(s), end(s), re, 1),
         sregex_token_iterator(),
         ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Результат:

```
as4s
s
sd4
sad
```

Answer (score 0):

В Perl есть "обратный просмотр": `/(?<!<)asd/` - строка 'asd', перед которой нет символа '<'. В JavaScript/C++ обратного просмотра нет, но можно использовать прямой: `/asd(?!>)/`.

Comment: Не достаточно negative lookahead здесь использовать. Если просто добавить `(?!>)` после `"[a-z][a-z0-9]*"`, то регулярное выражение просто пропустить начало слова, вместо того чтобы целиком его пропустить, например, `"<asd sad"` вернёт `sd sad` вместо просто `sad`.