# поиск первого слова в строке с помощью регулярных выражений на С++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Как запрограммировать поиск первого слова в строке с помощью регулярного выражения на С++? Много пересмотрел информации, а толкового нет ничего. Само регулярное выражение написал, а вот как поиск сделать не знаю...

Comment: А зачем для этого регулярные выражения??

Comment: Хм.. А реально, как? о_О

Comment: вопрос неясен--приведите явно регулярное выражение и/или примеры ввода/ожидаемого вывода.

Comment: @jfs, насколько я понимаю, спрашивается способ сделать на плюсах такое: `"Just a string :)".match(/\w+/)[0]`

Comment: @Qwertiy: чтобы не гадать, автору следует прояснить вопрос. Вот пара примеров кода: [Как получить часть строки, соответствующей регулярному выражению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524652/23044) и [Регулярное выражение для подстроки, которой не должен предшествовать символ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385337/23044)

Comment: @ jfs вот регулярное выражение, которое описывает первое слово в строке "^[A-Za-z]+\\s"

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. Придумал вот такой способ:

http://ideone.com/RESgso

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Just a string :)";

    string res = regex_replace(str, regex("^\\W*(\\w+).*$"), "$1");
    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

А как найти именно вхождения, что-то не гуглится :(